# Initial screen auto fadeout to app

Tags: iphone, ios7, fadeout

I am a master detail app which is embedded in tab bar controller. This loads from the beginning and works fine. Now, i want an initial page to load as soon as the app loads and then auto fade out to this screen without any event. How can i do the same? Please advice

Answer (score 0):

You can add the initial viewController in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Present your initial controller ontop of the UINavigationController that holds the rootViewController (with no animation).

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourRootViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

UIInitialController *initialControlller = [[UIInitialController alloc] init];
initialControlller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
initialControlller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[navigationController presentViewController:initialControlller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

When you are ready to dismiss your initial you can do this (from the UIInitialController class) - with animation (you can set a NSTimer to call this method automatically):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, a small query, in the first line, your rootviewcontroller, which name to enter here? whichever viewcontroller name i enter, it throws an error stating unexpected interfacename, expected expression, i cannot embed this inside a navigationcontroller since its already embedded inside tabbar controller

Comment: The rootViewController should be the first viewController that is displayed in your app. You should know the name of that class..(i dont :)) btw, if you are using master -detail controllers, it should probably be your masterViewController